# jquery and fancybox issue on internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, browser, fancybox

I am using fancybox on my portfolio page using jquery.  In internet explorer the fancybox opens underneath the page without the overlay effect or navigation control. There does not seem to be a problem in other browsers.  Please help!

http://www.iandale.net/clients/private/brydesign/index2.html

click on portfolio to see the issue.

the examples work without issue:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

thanks,
bryan

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with IE is because fancybox needs to be running in *standards* mode and currently your site is in *[quirks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode)* mode.

Try using a different `DOCTYPE` ... read [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) for more or simply set this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```